Lurie: left completeness vs. left separatedness (HA Prop 1.2.1.19)
I want to prove (the dual of) Proposition 1.2.1.19 in Lurie's Higher Algebra https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf in the setup of (pre)triangulated (dg-)categories with a t-structure. The statement is the following (note that Lurie uses homological notation, so the aisle is denoted by $\mathcal{T}_{\geq 0}$):
Proposition. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a stable infinity-category equipped with a t-structure. Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ has countable products and that $\mathcal{C}_{\geq 0}$ is stable under them. The following conditions are equivalent:

The $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}$ is left complete;
$\bigcap_{n \geq 0} \mathcal{C}_{\geq n} = 0$.

My question:
In the proof, it is said that fib$(\theta')$ can be identified with the limit of a tower $\{$fib$(f(m) → f(n − 1))\}_{m<n}$. When I try to show this in the proof of the dual statement in my setup, I need that the homotopy colimits of a countable family of exact triangles form an exact triangle. This does not hold in general for triangulated categories. So we really need the enhancement here?
